# How to keep child entity on database when we delete main entity

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, cascading-deletes

I am using Hibernate and have one to many relation in my entity.

```
public MyClass{

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<MyObject> myObject= new HashSet<>();

     // some other fields
}
```

MyObject is actually not only child entity. It is main entity in my application. Therefore when I delete MyClass entity, I do not want to delete myObject which is in the MyObject table on database.

My usage is on that way:

1) Persisting MyClass entity, so MyObject entities are also persisted.
2) Later I need to remove MyClass entity but need to keep MyObject records which was persisted on the first step.

I tried to use `CascadeType.PERSIST` but it creates a select query to MyObject table and as it can't find the records for the given myObject objects, it throws exception. Therefore I am using `CascadeType.ALL`. But in this time, when I delete the entity by deleteById method of JpaRepository, it deletes MyObject entities as well.

How can I perform deletion without deleting MyObject entities ?

Comment: Cascade.PERSIST and Cascade.MERGE would be the right way. What kind of excpetion do you get`?

Comment: CascadeType.MERGE works. But PERSIST does not work. When I am trying to persist, it creates select query for the child entity and throws EntityNotFoundException. I think hibernate thinks that entity already exists. But Merge works actually. But still I do not know why PERSIST does not work.

Comment: If you want avoid select of the child entities you should use `FetchType.LAZY` instead of `FetchType.EAGER`. See also [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/)

Comment: I want to select them in that case it is ok. I just do not want to delete them when I delete main entity. Cascade.MERGE works for this. But I do not understand why Cascade.PERSIST does not work.

Comment: How does the SQL statement look like it creates?

Comment: @user1474111, From one side you are talking about entity deleting, from the other side about the `Cascade.PERSIST` property that affect behavior of the `EntityManager.persist()` method. So, to clarify the question, could you please provide code snippet that will show what exactly you want to accomplish.